# iOS Safari input attributes uppercase?

Tags: ios, html, input, safari, mobile-safari

I know there's a way to disable the first-letter-capitalization in iOS Safari, but is there a way to engage caps-lock?

Like:

```
<input type="text" autocapitalize="all" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 <input type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:14px" />
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `autocapitalize="characters"` to your input/textarea.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html